# highcharts - setting step on axis dynamically

Tags: highcharts

Can anyone help me set step value on x-axis or y-axis dynamically say on clicking a button (not at the design time). In the example below, I should be able to set the step/interval as 100 instead of 250.

here is the example fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/PanicJ/H2pyC/8/

```
$(function () {
var setA = [29.9, 11.5, 36.4, 19.2, 4.0, 46.0, 48.2, 15.2, 16.4, 4.1, 5.6, 44.4];
var setB = [129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 248.5, 316.4, 694.1, 795.6, 954.4, 1029.9, 1171.5, 1506.4];
var data = Math.random() < 0.5 ? setA : setB;
var height=Math.max.apply(Math, data);
if(height > 1000){
    height = 1000;
}
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        marginRight: 80 // like left
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 1,
        max: height,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Primary Axis'
        }
    }],
    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 2):

The tickInterval is what you want to change:

```
$('#setStep').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.yAxis[0].update({
        tickInterval: 100
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/H2pyC/85/